# Problem with saving data in array o Angular and Typescript

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular11

The problem: my benchmark `foreach loop` does not save all the values into the array, instead, it saves one and gives error null. if I remove the push and made a `console.log` instead it does however show all results.

```
  onGetResults() {
    this.accountService.getBenchmark(this.user.id)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        benchmarks => {
          this.benchmarks = benchmarks;
          const benchmarkDates: any[] = null;
          const benchmarkValues: any[] = null;
          this.benchmarks.forEach(data => {
            let becnchmarkDate: any = data.createdAt;
            benchmarkDates.push(becnchmarkDate);
            benchmarkValues.push(data.benchmarkResults);
          });
          const allData = {
            label: benchmarkDates,
            data: benchmarkValues,
            fill: true
          }
          this.benchmarkChart[0] = new Chart({
            type: 'radar',
            data: allData,
            options: {
              elements: {
                line: {
                  borderWidth: 3
                }
              }
            }
          });
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: Just do a null check before pushing the value into the array, may be your array contains null values ?  or declare array like this & give it a try, let benchmarkdates: string[];

Comment: null check did it for me thank you @VenkateshK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried to set the declaration of the array outside of the function for some clean code and performance reason ,

```
const benchmarkDates: any[] = null;
const benchmarkValues: any[] = null;

onGetResults() {
  this.accountService.getBenchmark(this.user.id)
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(
      benchmarks => {
        this.benchmarks = benchmarks;
     
        this.benchmarks.forEach(data => {
          benchmarkDates.push(data.createdAt;);
          benchmarkValues.push(data.benchmarkResults);
        });
        const allData = {
          label: benchmarkDates,
          data: benchmarkValues,
          fill: true
        }
        this.benchmarkChart[0] = new Chart({
          type: 'radar',
          data: allData,
          options: {
            elements: {
              line: {
                borderWidth: 3
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
    );
}
```